# How to split a certain number from a string but keep another number in that string still in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, split

So I have a strings like this

```
"name": "Monochrome / Black & White 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini"

"name": "Monochrome / Black & White Metallic 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini (PR=300 pieces)"

"name": "799 Dracula with Candle - Walgreens"

"name": "114 The Wolf Man Flocked - Toy Tokyo 2016 San Diego Comic-Con"

 "name": "111 Dracula"

 "name": "111 Dracula & Creator : 2-pack"

 "name": "Funko Pop #111 Dracula & Creator : 2-pack"
```

I would only need to split the beginning numbers that are the actual funko pop #, not a number if it was a date, or 2-pack, or where it says the amount of pieces. I would still want those numbers in the name string, but i want to take out the funko pop number to look something like this

```
"name": "Monochrome / Black & White 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini"

"name": "Monochrome / Black & White Metallic 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini (PR=300 pieces)"

"name": "Dracula with Candle - Walgreens"

"name": "The Wolf Man Flocked - Toy Tokyo 2016 San Diego Comic-Con"

 "name": "Dracula"

 "name": "Dracula & Creator : 2-pack"

 "name": "Funko Pop Dracula & Creator : 2-pack"
```

I am making an object for each funko when I scrape websites which look like this:

```
{
    "genre": "Ultimate Funko Pop Universal Monsters Figures Gallery and Checklist",
    "funkoData": [
      {
        "number": "111",
        "name": "111 Dracula",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Dracula.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "112",
        "name": "112 Frankenstein",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Frankenstein.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "112",
        "name": "112 Frankenstein Glow-in-the-Dark - Hot Topic",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Frankenstein-GITD.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "113",
        "name": "113 The Bride of Frankenstein",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Bride-of-Frankenstein.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "113",
        "name": "113 The Bride of Frankenstein Glow-in-the-Dark - Hot Topic",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Bride-of-Frankenstein-GITD.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "114",
        "name": "114 The Wolf Man",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Wolf-Man.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "114",
        "name": "114 The Wolf Man Flocked - Toy Tokyo 2016 San Diego Comic-Con",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-114-The-Wolf-Man-Flocked-Toy-Tokyo-2016-San-Diego-Comic-Con-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "114",
        "name": "114 The Wolf Man Glow-in-the-Dark - Toy Tokyo 2016 New York Comic Con",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/2016-Funko-New-York-Comic-Con-Exclusives-Pop-Monsters-114-Glow-in-the-Dark-Wolfman-Toy-Tokyo.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "115",
        "name": "115 The Mummy",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Mummy.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "116",
        "name": "116 Creature from the Black Lagoon",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Creature-from-the-Black-Lagoon.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "116",
        "name": "116 Creature from the Black Lagoon Glow-in-the-Dark - Gemini",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-116-Creature-from-the-Black-Lagoon-Glow-in-the-Dark-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "116",
        "name": "116 Creature from the Black Lagoon Metallic - Gemini",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-116-Creature-from-the-Black-Lagoon-Metallic-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "117",
        "name": "117 The Phantom of the Opera",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Phantom-of-the-Opera.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "118",
        "name": "118 Metaluna Mutant",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Metaluna-Mutant.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "607",
        "name": "607 Frankenstein with flower - Walgreens",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-607-Frankenstein-with-flower-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "607",
        "name": "607 Frankenstein Glow-in-the-Dark - Walgreens",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-607-Frankenstein-Glow-in-the-Dark-GITD-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "608",
        "name": "608 The Invisible Man - Walgreens",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-608-The-Invisible-Clear-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "608",
        "name": "608 The Invisible Man Clear Chase Variant - Walgreens",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-608-The-Invisible-Man-Clear-Chase-Variant-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "608",
        "name": "608 The Invisible Man Black & White with Book - Walgreens",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-608-The-Invisible-Man-Black-White-with-book-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "799",
        "name": "799 Dracula with Candle - Walgreens",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-799-Dracula-with-Candle-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": null,
        "name": "Kirk Hammett Collection (Metallica) - Royal Ontario Museum ROM",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Ultimate-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Kirk-Hammett-Collection-Royal-Ontario-Museum-Exclusives.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "16",
        "name": "Icons 16 Creature from the Black Lagoon / 17 Frankenstein (PR=1,008 pieces each)",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Ultimate-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Kirk-Hammett-Collection-Royal-Ontario-Museum-Exclusives.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": null,
        "name": "Funko Pop Universal Monsters Combo Figures",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Black-White-4-Pack-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "4",
        "name": "Monochrome / Black & White 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Black-White-4-Pack-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
      },
      {
        "number": "4",
        "name": "Monochrome / Black & White Metallic 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini (PR=300 pieces)",
        "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Black-White-Metallic-4-Pack-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So I can get the number out of the name but now i just want to take out like the example above.

Anyone know a good way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I mean I am not entirely sure if this is what you want but have you looked at [duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling)? It finds some useful things inside of your strings. Take a closer look at the URL Dimension.

However, the specific thing you want is pretty complex and I think to really tackle the problem, you have to code it yourself. There are no custom solutions out there. If duckling doesn't work, try just learning regex for real.

Answer (score 0):

First create an array of the funko pop numbers (here obj is the object that contains `genre` and `funkoData`:

```
var nums = obj.funkoData.map((item) => {
  return item.number;
});
```

Now that you have all funko pop numbers in an array, you can strip of the number at the beginning of each string and check it against your `nums` array:

```
str = "799 Dracula with Candle - Walgreens" // Example string
startingNum = str.match(/(\d+)*/)[1];
if(nums.indexOf(startingNum) > -1) {
  str = str..replace(/(\d+\s)/,"");
}
return str;
```

Here is the full code in action:

```js
var obj = {
  "genre": "Ultimate Funko Pop Universal Monsters Figures Gallery and Checklist",
  "funkoData": [{
      "number": "111",
      "name": "111 Dracula",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Dracula.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "112",
      "name": "112 Frankenstein",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Frankenstein.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "112",
      "name": "112 Frankenstein Glow-in-the-Dark - Hot Topic",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Frankenstein-GITD.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "113",
      "name": "113 The Bride of Frankenstein",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Bride-of-Frankenstein.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "113",
      "name": "113 The Bride of Frankenstein Glow-in-the-Dark - Hot Topic",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Bride-of-Frankenstein-GITD.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "114",
      "name": "114 The Wolf Man",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Wolf-Man.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "114",
      "name": "114 The Wolf Man Flocked - Toy Tokyo 2016 San Diego Comic-Con",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-114-The-Wolf-Man-Flocked-Toy-Tokyo-2016-San-Diego-Comic-Con-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "114",
      "name": "114 The Wolf Man Glow-in-the-Dark - Toy Tokyo 2016 New York Comic Con",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/2016-Funko-New-York-Comic-Con-Exclusives-Pop-Monsters-114-Glow-in-the-Dark-Wolfman-Toy-Tokyo.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "115",
      "name": "115 The Mummy",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Mummy.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "116",
      "name": "116 Creature from the Black Lagoon",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Creature-from-the-Black-Lagoon.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "116",
      "name": "116 Creature from the Black Lagoon Glow-in-the-Dark - Gemini",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-116-Creature-from-the-Black-Lagoon-Glow-in-the-Dark-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "116",
      "name": "116 Creature from the Black Lagoon Metallic - Gemini",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-116-Creature-from-the-Black-Lagoon-Metallic-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "117",
      "name": "117 The Phantom of the Opera",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Phantom-of-the-Opera.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "118",
      "name": "118 Metaluna Mutant",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Metaluna-Mutant.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "607",
      "name": "607 Frankenstein with flower - Walgreens",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-607-Frankenstein-with-flower-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "607",
      "name": "607 Frankenstein Glow-in-the-Dark - Walgreens",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-607-Frankenstein-Glow-in-the-Dark-GITD-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "608",
      "name": "608 The Invisible Man - Walgreens",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-608-The-Invisible-Clear-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "608",
      "name": "608 The Invisible Man Clear Chase Variant - Walgreens",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-608-The-Invisible-Man-Clear-Chase-Variant-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "608",
      "name": "608 The Invisible Man Black & White with Book - Walgreens",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-608-The-Invisible-Man-Black-White-with-book-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "799",
      "name": "799 Dracula with Candle - Walgreens",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Figures-799-Dracula-with-Candle-Walgreens-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": null,
      "name": "Kirk Hammett Collection (Metallica) - Royal Ontario Museum ROM",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Ultimate-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Kirk-Hammett-Collection-Royal-Ontario-Museum-Exclusives.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "16",
      "name": "Icons 16 Creature from the Black Lagoon / 17 Frankenstein (PR=1,008 pieces each)",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Ultimate-Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Kirk-Hammett-Collection-Royal-Ontario-Museum-Exclusives.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": null,
      "name": "Funko Pop Universal Monsters Combo Figures",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Black-White-4-Pack-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "4",
      "name": "Monochrome / Black & White 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Black-White-4-Pack-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
    },
    {
      "number": "4",
      "name": "Monochrome / Black & White Metallic 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini (PR=300 pieces)",
      "image": "https://cconnect.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Funko-Pop-Universal-Monsters-Black-White-Metallic-4-Pack-Gemini-Exclusive.jpg"
    }
  ]
};

var names = [
  "Monochrome / Black & White 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini",
  "Monochrome / Black & White Metallic 4-Pack (Wolf Man, Creature from Black Lagoon, Dracula, Frankenstein) - Gemini (PR=300 pieces)",
  "799 Dracula with Candle - Walgreens",
  "114 The Wolf Man Flocked - Toy Tokyo 2016 San Diego Comic-Con",
  "111 Dracula",
  "111 Dracula & Creator : 2-pack",
  "Funko Pop #111 Dracula & Creator : 2-pack"
];

var nums = obj.funkoData.map((item) => {
  return item.number;
});

function removeFunkoPopNum(str) {
  startingNum = str.match(/(\d+)*/)[1];
  if (nums.indexOf(startingNum) > -1) {
    str = str.replace(/(\d+\s)/, "");
  }
  return str;
}

for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  console.log(removeFunkoPopNum(names[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use a regex like `^(\d+)\s(.*)` to look for the number at the beginning of the string.

- `^` is the beginning of the string or line (depending on regex modifiers)
- `()` wrap the captured groups so you can treat the contents independently.
- `\d+` finds the digit string
- `.*` finds the rest of the string (unless it contains a newline depending on regex modifiers)

If the above regex matches, then the first capture group would contain the number and the second contains the title.  If it doesn't match, then you could use the full string as the title.

This might not be what you want for a title like `1984`.